# How to write JSON data on HTTP with Python?

Tags: python

I am using a Raspberry Pi 4 to connect to the server through computer's mobile hotspot. I want to post my JSON data that the Raspberry Pi read on the HTTP page of Raspberry Pi's connected IP with Python code.

```
import requests, Adafruit_DHT, time, json
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

sensor = Adafruit_DHT.AM2302 #DHT11/DHT22/AM2302
pin = 4
url = 'http://192.168.137.86:3350/temperature_humidity'
latest_humidity              = 0.0
latest_temperature           = 0.0
headers = {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
}
params = (
    ('priority', 'normal'),
)



def write_hist_value_callback():
  hum, temp = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(sensor, pin)
  if hum is not None and temp is not None:
      if temp < -40.0 or temp > 80.0:
        print "Ignoring out of range temperature: {0:0.1f}*".format(temp)
      else:
        latest_temperature = temp
      if hum < 0.0 or hum > 100.0:
        print "Ignoring out of range humidity: {0:0.1f}%".format(hum)
      else:
        latest_humidity = hum
      payload = {'temperature': latest_temperature ,'humidity': latest_humidity}
      print json.dumps(payload)

print "Ignoring first 2 sensor values to improve quality..."
for x in range(2):
  Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(sensor, pin)

print "Creating interval timer. This step takes almost 2 minutes on the Raspberry Pi..."
#create timer that is called every n seconds, without accumulating delays as when using sleep
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
#scheduler.add_job(write_hist_value_callback, 'interval', seconds=60)
scheduler.start()
print "Started interval timer which will be called the first time in {0} seconds.".format(60);

try:
  while True:
    hum, temp = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(sensor, pin)
    if hum is not None and temp is not None:
      if temp < -40.0 or temp > 80.0:
        print "Ignoring out of range temperature: {0:0.1f}*".format(temp)
      else:
        latest_temperature = temp #"{:.2f}".format(temp)
      if hum < 0.0 or hum > 100.0:
        print "Ignoring out of range humidity: {0:0.1f}%".format(hum)
      else:
        latest_humidity = hum #"{:.2f}".format(hum)
      payload = {'temperature': latest_temperature ,'humidity': latest_humidity}
      print json.dumps(payload)


    time.sleep(60)
except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
  scheduler.shutdown()
```

What do I need to do to make it write the JSON on URL? The URL that I need to write JSON on is `http://192.168.137.86:3350/temperature_humidity` (It is the IP of the board connected to internet)

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at HTTP POST requests and `requests.post`. It seems that you imported `requests` but didn't do anything with it.

Comment: I did tried using request.post before in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60474758/python-request-gives-cannot-post-response , problem is I can't find the right URL to post it to. I wonder where can I find the URL that allowed me to post it. I don't know how to set it up.

Comment: This question is not actually about JSON at all, since there is already code that can create the desired JSON data (`json.dumps(payload)`). The question is purely about how to send data over an Internet connection, and should have been asked as such. Please see [mre].